# Most efficient Database representation of hierarchical data?

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, hierarchical-data

I have a web app that I've made that I now want to make WELL. It contains a large tree that I want to persist in a database. The tree will be about 50 nodes wide and 30 nodes deep. It will have frequent reads and writes to mostly single nodes, but copying/pasting subtrees is possible.

I've already implemented it using Nested Intervals. But the implementation of this that I used  (Node key encoding) causes very large integers to occur when the tree gets deep.

My question is: what is the most efficient representation of hierarchical data that we know of today?

Thanks,
Marco.

Comment: is the tree a DAG? can childrens be shared among parents?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree)

Comment: definitely not a duplicate. this question is more about how to best design a database to efficiently hold hierarchical data. the SO you provided is about taking existing data and making a tree from it. while it provides one way to hold hierarchical data, it doesn't answer the question asked here.